# VBScript : Set clipboard to variable & return the variable

Tags: javascript, vbscript, return

I am using a program that allows running scripts. I copied an excel table and assigned a variable. After that if use WScript.Echo ı can see the copied table but if I use WScript.Stdout.WriteLine to be able to return the copied table I could return just the first row of the table but I need all table. Are there any other option for returning clipboard or directly excel table? Thanks.

I shared below a part of my code with you

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 

objExcel.Visible = False 

Set tempbook4 = objExcel.Workbooks.Add   'I created tempbook4 with some excel operations 

set shtTemp4=tempbook4.Sheets(1)

Set objRange = shtTemp4.Range("A1:L7")

objRange.Copy

Set objHTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")

result4 = objHTML.ParentWindow.ClipboardData.GetData("text")

Set objRange=Nothing

Set objHTML =Nothing

WScript.StdOut.WriteLine result4
```

Comment: `.writelines` write lines.

Comment: i treid but it did not work.